# ValueError: The view app.views.plus_cart didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

```
views.py

from django.db.models import Count
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from . models import Product, Cart, Customer
from . forms import CustomerRegistrationFrom, CustomerProfileForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.db.models import Q

def show_cart(request):
    user = request.user
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
    amount = 0
    for p in cart:
        value =p.quantity * p.product.discounted_price
        amount = amount + value 
    totalamount = amount + 40
    return render(request,'app/addtocart.html',locals())


def plus_cart(request):
    if request.method == 'Get':
        prod_id=request.Get['prod_id']
        c = Cart.objects.get(Q(product=prod_id) & Q (user=request.user))
        c.quantity += 1
        c.save()
        user = request.user
        cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
        amount = 0
        for p in cart:
            value = p.quantity * p.product.discounted_price
            amount = amount + value
        totalamount = amount + 40
        print(prod_id)
        data={
            'quantity':c.quantity,
            'amount':amount,
            'totalamount':totalamount
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)

script.py


$('.plus-cart').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("pid").toString();
    var eml=this.parentNode.children[2] 
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/pluscart",
        data:{
            prod_id:id
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log("data = ",data)
            eml.innerText=data.quantity 
            document.getElementById("amount").innerText=data.amount 
            document.getElementById("totalamount").innerText=data.totalamount
        }
    })
})
```

```
Internal Server Error: /pluscart/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SIRI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\SIRI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 204, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "C:\Users\SIRI\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 332, in check_response
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The view app.views.plus_cart didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[06/May/2023 18:23:59] "GET /pluscart/?prod_id=1 HTTP/1.1" 500 66757
```

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
request.method == "GET"
```

instead of Get.

Same for

```
prod_id=request.GET[...]
```